# Index route not being generates by resource command in routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a ruby on rails app, I have the following routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/index'
  get 'pages/about'
  root to: 'pages#index'
  resource :graphs, only: [:index, :create, :show, :destroy]
end
```

This generates the routes for graphs#create, graphs#show, graphs#destroy but not for graphs#index.  I think the reason for this is that when I generated the controller I used `rails g controller Graph`, i.e. I used the singular version instead of the plural of Graphs. To fix this I changed the corresponding file and directory names i.e. controller/graphs_controller.rb  and views/graphs, and I changed the constant in graphs_controller.rb to GraphsController.  Everything seems to work except for the index route not being generated.  I can fix it by changing the resource declaration to

```
  resource :graphs, only: [:create, :show, :destroy] do
    get :index
  end
```

but this seems messy. It seems I need to change something else to make the transition from graph to graphs. How do I fix this?  Note that I have restarted the server several times.

Comment: You're using `resource` and not `resources`. The singular version is for singular resources where the only ever can be one. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `resources` instead of `resource`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/index'
  get 'pages/about'
  root to: 'pages#index'
  resources :graphs, only: [:index, :create, :show, :destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be **resources** instead of **resource**